# What is the Matlab/Octave equivalent or R's 'merge' (or 'expand.grid')?

Tags: r, matlab

I am looking for the Matlab way of doing the following:

```
> merge(2:4,3:7)
   x y
1  2 3
2  3 3
3  4 3
4  2 4
5  3 4
6  4 4
7  2 5
8  3 5
9  4 5
10 2 6
11 3 6
12 4 6
13 2 7
14 3 7
15 4 7
> expand.grid(2:4,3:7)
   Var1 Var2
1     2    3
2     3    3
3     4    3
4     2    4
5     3    4
6     4    4
7     2    5
8     3    5
9     4    5
10    2    6
11    3    6
12    4    6
13    2    7
14    3    7
15    4    7
```

Comment: I just found a way using Neural Network's Toolbox "combvec". But it doesn't exist in Octave

Comment: I didn't find anything useful in http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.html ... you might be able to put something together using `meshgrid` http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html ?

Comment: It looks like the equivalent of `merge` is `join` (not really too surprising): http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.join.html -- but that's not really what you're using `merge` for above ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually do it with `meshgrid`:

```
>> [x y] = meshgrid(2:4, 3:7);
>> [x(:) y(:)]

ans =

     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
     2     6
     2     7
     3     3
     3     4
     3     5
     3     6
     3     7
     4     3
     4     4
     4     5
     4     6
     4     7
```

Comment: This works great for 2 vectors but meshgrid does not accept more than 2.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ndgrid` for n variables (2 and more). For example  (4-D space)

```
[X,Y,Z,T] = ndgrid(2:4, 3:7, 1:2, 1:10);
```